# Sed/bash to append partial filename and date to new filename in bash

Tags: bash, sed

I have a bunch of csv files in a folder. I need a sed/bash script to accomplish the following for each file in the folder:

Take filename.csv, execute a script with each file, and paste the result of the execution into filename+CurrentDate.csv where current date is only the date without spaces.

For example: 
abc.csv is turned into abc_02-03-15.csv after a function is performed on it.

I figure the code would look something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir="/var/tmp/"
now=$(date)
for f in "$dir"/*; do
   ScriptName
   sed OriginalFileName > "OriginalFileName+$now.csv" 
done
```

Please advise and thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your filtering script takes its input on stdin and writes to stdout:

```
dir="/var/tmp/"
now=$(date "+%Y-%m-%d")
for f in "$dir"/*; do
   ScriptName <"$f" >"${f}_$now.csv"
done
```

As should be fairly obvious, within the loop, `$f` refers to the input name. When that's being substituted into part of a string with characters that are valid variable names after it, it's necessary to use curly braces to disambiguate: `$f_$now.csv` would be looking for a variable named `f_`, not `f`.

The dates, here, are in YYYY-MM-DD form. This is **STRONGLY** preferable to DD-MM-YY or MM-DD-YY for a few reasons: It sorts in lexographical order identically to its numeric order (so tools that do a plain ASCII sort, like `ls`, will show files named in this way newest-to-oldest or oldest-to-newest), and it's unambiguous for human readers, whether they come from countries where DD-MM or MM-DD is conventional.

Comment: This appears to have worked inside the for loop. Trying to do it outside of the for loop is a bit problematic. I have a simple script as follows: file1=abc.csv, file2="${file1%.*}", now=$(date), file3=$file1_$file2, echo "$file3". This only displays abc and not abc followed by the date.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean there. Could you clarify the remaining issue (or link to any new question asked, should it be outside the scope of the existing question)?

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is display the file+date outside of a loop. A correction from my previous comment is file3=$file2_$now. echo "
$file3" shows abc but does not show the date

Comment: That wouldn't work as-given -- it would need to be `file3=${file2}_$now`. With that correction, though, it runs fine; see http://ideone.com/qlMfRQ. If you have an example showing this _not_ working for you, please provide it in a similar fashion -- with a standalone reproducer.